# SQL Authentication vs Windows Authentication

Tags: sql-server

In our server application we use single account to access to the SQL Server. We used to use SQL Authentication. Now we are thinking to remove credentials from config files; and one of the solutions is to use Windows Authentication.

We are mostly concerned about performance. Is there any differences?

Another problem, is domain controller that occasionally could be down. Is SQL will be able authenticate in this case?

What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't see any noticeable performance issues, assuming that all is well with your network and domain.  You'll most likely see impersonation / delegation problems before you start seeing performance issues.

Comment: Thatnks, yet another question. What will be in case domain controller is down? Application will not be able to connect? Does SQL server cache something?

Comment: It's possible that your app won't be able to connect, but it will depend on when access tokens are created for the app process.  If you only have one domain controller and it goes down you'll have bigger problems than just your app's authentication, though.